# Run startx & automatically embedded syste,

Tags: shell-script, embedded, startx

I am working with a board in which I run my application which use th graphical mode. Everything works perfect. I start the graphical mode like this:

```
startx &
```

and then I run my application like this:

```
./myApplication
```

And it works

The Problem is that I want to run the graphical mode automatically, I mean I want to switch the board on and see the graphical mode, then I just need to run my application. Is it that possible?

I tried to add to the init.d a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#Start
#
echo "Start......"
ifconfig eth0 X.X.X.X
startx &
exit $?
```

I rename this like S80Example.sh and add to the init.d, and it seems that works, but the graphic mode is not load propertly, and not works fine.

How can I solved this?

Thank you so much

Comment: how does it not work? What is it doing? What are the error messages?

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for your quick answer. there is not a message error, it seem that si ok, but on the screen start the graphic mode but like deconfigurate. Do I need somenthing for run the startx &?

Comment: Appear a windows with "x" for close on the screen, and the when I try to show something appear six square, forming a square. Do I need login as root for run the startx?

Comment: _XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/FSiMX6:0
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6

Comment: I found those errors when is booting

Comment: Nobody knows anything about this subject?

Comment: I found some information and I tried somethings but is not working, maybe I ma doing something wrong, here is the links: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Login

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173388